# How I can use pino as a logger?

Tags: node.js, logging, pinojs

I'm just starting out using pino with pino-pretty. I really looked for documentation to learn how to use it but I found it difficult to understand how to implement it to my application. Could anyone give me some help please?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a quick example with a basic prettifier - in case you're not happy with the native JSON output.

```
const { EOL } = require('os');
const levelMapping = { 50: 'error', 40: 'warning', 30: 'info', 20: 'debug' };

const logger = pino({
    level: level,
    prettyPrint: {},
    prettifier: (opts) => {
        return (inputData) => {
            const ts = new Date().toISOString().replace(/T/, ' ').replace(/\..+/, '');
            const line = `${ts} ${levelMapping[inputData.level]}: ${inputData.msg} ${EOL}`
            return line;
        }
    }
});
```

And then of course:

```
logger.info('I like it');
// outputs: 2020-08-21 15:10:17 info: i like it
```

Answer (score 0):

This no JSON:

```
const logger = require('pino')({
    level: process.env.LOG_LEVEL,
    prettyPrint: true
 });
```

This JSON:

```
const logger = require('pino')({
    level: process.env.LOG_LEVEL,
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to updated my package.json to have the following dependencies with the following versions:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@hapi/hapi": "^18.4.0",
    "hapi-pino": "^6.3.0"
    }
```

After running the npm install and starting the project the logger was logging.